# Use of "OR" and "INTERSECT" in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have only one Table TableA like below :

| ID | Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | BS | 12-APR-22 |
| First | GH | 10-MAY-22 |
| First | MPN | 15-APR-22 |
| Second | BS | 10-MAY-22 |
| Second | MPN | 10-MAY-22 |
| Third | GH | 10-MAY-22 |
| Third | BS | 10-MAY-22 |
| Fourth | MPN | 15-MAY-22 |
| Fourth | GH | 15-MAY-22 |
| Fifth | GH | 06-MAY-22 |

I want to achieve output as below :

| ID | Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | BS | 12-APR-22 |
| First | GH | 10-MAY-22 |
| First | MPN | 15-APR-22 |
| Second | BS | 10-MAY-22 |
| Second | MPN | 10-MAY-22 |
| Third | GH | 10-MAY-22 |
| Third | BS | 10-MAY-22 |

I have the query as below but I'm not seeing any output :

```
Select ID from TableA 
WHERE 
(DATE BETWEEN '13-APR-22' AND '11-MAY-22') 
AND
(
(TYPE = 'BS' AND TYPE = 'GH') 
OR
(TYPE = 'GH' AND TYPE = 'MPN') 
OR
(TYPE = 'BS' AND TYPE = 'MPN')

);
```

I have also tried the following but I'm getting an error in the output :

```
Select ID from TableA WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '13-APR-22' AND '11-MAY-22') AND (TYPE = 'BS')

INTERSECT

Select ID from TableA WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '13-APR-22' AND '11-MAY-22') AND (TYPE = 'GH')

OR

Select ID from TableA WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '13-APR-22' AND '11-MAY-22') AND (TYPE = 'GH')

INTERSECT

Select ID from TableA WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '13-APR-22' AND '11-MAY-22') AND (TYPE = 'MPN')

OR

Select ID from TableA WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '13-APR-22' AND '11-MAY-22') AND (TYPE = 'BS')

INTERSECT

Select ID from TableA WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '13-APR-22' AND '11-MAY-22') AND (TYPE = 'MPN')
```

Please help me in achieving the output that I'm looking for. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the _type_ of the `Date` column?  Is it storing text or actual dates?

Comment: `TYPE = 'BS' AND TYPE = 'GH'` is a contradiction.

Comment: @JeffHolt ... that's not the intended logic

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What you said is obvious. What I said is not, apparently for one.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen - Data Column storing actual Dates

Comment: Can you express in human language what your criteria are for including rows? Neither of your SQL statements expresses that clearly to me, nor does your table.

Comment: @RossPresser It appears to be "Select all the rows for each ID if, for that ID and within the date range 2022-04-13 to 2022-05-11, there exists a pair of rows that have the types of either: `BS` and `GH`; `BS` and `MPN`; or `GH` and `MPN`."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an aggregation approach here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID
    FROM TableA
    WHERE "DATE" BETWEEN date '2022-04-13' AND date '2022-05-11'
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING
        (COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'BS' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
         COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'GH' THEN 1 END) > 0)
        OR
        (COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'GH' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
         COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'MPN' THEN 1 END) > 0)
        OR
        (COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'BS' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
         COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'MPN' THEN 1 END) > 0)
)

SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM cte);
```

Comment: While the parser may understand perfectly which of the `AND` / `OR` clauses is meant to have precedence, humans may not. At least this human doesn't. Multiple identical subclauses separated by conjunctions is just plain weird.

Comment: @RossPresser Answer updated, but it looks uglier to me now.

Comment: @RossPresser - I hear that a lot. My preferred answer is that people who don't know the precedence of AND/OR should not be writing code. Precedence of AND/OR is several levels more basic than other critical but equally trivial things one needs to know in order to write code.

Comment: @mathguy Sorry. Since parentheses are inexpensive, I haven't devoted brain cells to remembering such a fact.  *edit* Well, I guess I did remember such a fact back when adding two bytes to a source code line worried me. Maybe last thought about it circa, I dunno, 1993?

Comment: Since @mathguy mentioned parentheses and AND/OR precedence, I would put parentheses around the whole `HAVING` clause.  I enclose all disjunctions (`OR` expressions) in parentheses because it's too common (in my experience) for a developer to come along later with another condition and just tack on `AND whatever...`, not realizing he's only adding it to the last expression in the `OR`.  It's just a defensive measure.

Answer (score 0):

Use analytic functions and conditional aggregation so you do not have to query the table twice:

```sql
SELECT id, type, "DATE"
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(
           CASE
           WHEN TYPE = 'BS'
           AND  "DATE" >= DATE '2022-04-13'
           AND  "DATE" <  DATE '2022-05-12'
           THEN 1
           END
         ) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS num_bs,
         COUNT(
           CASE
           WHEN TYPE = 'GH'
           AND  "DATE" >= DATE '2022-04-13'
           AND  "DATE" <  DATE '2022-05-12'
           THEN 1
           END
         ) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS num_gh,
         COUNT(
           CASE
           WHEN TYPE = 'MPN'
           AND  "DATE" >= DATE '2022-04-13'
           AND  "DATE" <  DATE '2022-05-12'
           THEN 1
           END
         ) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS num_mpn
  FROM   tableA t
)
WHERE (num_bs > 0 AND num_gh > 0)
OR    (num_bs > 0 AND num_mpn > 0)
OR    (num_gh > 0 AND num_mpn > 0)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tablea (ID, Type, "DATE") AS
SELECT 'First',  'BS',  DATE '2022-04-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'First',  'GH',  DATE '2022-05-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'First',  'MPN', DATE '2022-04-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Second', 'BS',  DATE '2022-05-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Second', 'MPN', DATE '2022-05-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Third',  'GH',  DATE '2022-05-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Third',  'BS',  DATE '2022-05-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fourth', 'MPN', DATE '2022-05-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fourth', 'GH',  DATE '2022-05-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fifth',  'GH',  DATE '2022-05-06' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | TYPE | DATE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | First | GH | 10-MAY-22 |
> | First | MPN | 15-APR-22 |
> | First | BS | 12-APR-22 |
> | Second | BS | 10-MAY-22 |
> | Second | MPN | 10-MAY-22 |
> | Third | GH | 10-MAY-22 |
> | Third | BS | 10-MAY-22 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e62683ddc16e6c1ec884c769311e4c37)*